# Is $\{n: n = 3k + 1\}$ a unique factorization domain? (We are factoring into numbers of form $3k + 1$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Call a number of form $3k + 1$ a  prime if and only it cannot be factored into smaller numbers all of form $3k + 1$. The set of all numbers of this form is obviously closed, and every number of this form clearly has at least one factorization. Is it unique? Prove or give counterexample.

Comment: note that $10^2 = 4*25$

Comment: Hint: $\ 2^{\large 2} 5^{\large 2} = (2\cdot 5)^{\large 2}\ \ $  Unique factorization *monoid*, not domain.

Comment: Also: this set is not a unique factorization domain, because it is not a ring, lacking zero (much less a domain).

Comment: See also [this thread](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/a-non-unique-factorization-of-integers/6113#comment18562_6113) for further discussion, including literature references.

Comment: Another way to find a counterexample, not necessarily the smallest one, is to multiply four numbers of the form $3k + 2$, preferably all pairwise coprime. Then the resulting number might have three distinct factorizations into numbers of the form $3k + 1$. e.g., 880.

Answer (score 5):

I can tell that what you meant to ask is whether every number of the form $3k + 1$, with $k \geq 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be uniquely factored into numbers of that form. The answer is no.

The first few numbers are $$1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, \ldots$$

Just looking at these few numbers, one may be led astray and think that there is indeed unique factorization among them. Mwahahaha!

But here's one way to find a bunch of counterexamples: think of a prime number $p$ of the form $3k - 1$. Then $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and so is $2p$. Then $4p^2 = (2p)^2$, readily leading to the examples $100 = 4 \times 25 = 10^2$, $484 = 4 \times 121 = 22^2$, $1156 = 4 \times 289 = 34^2$, etc.

Not too different from $4k + 1$.